# endless recyclerview doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i'm making app for clothes and i need to make endless recyclerview .. i could fetch al the data but i couldn't make pagination , i tried many solution but nothing works fine , that's my code for the page and image for the firebase database of recyclerview's data.

**Image for the firebase**
[image: Image for the firebase]

**code:**

```
private View mMainView;
private String user_id;
private RecyclerView mUserList;
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private List<ItemsRecyclerView> mItems;
private ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private String oldestkey;


public Items() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    mUserList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.items_recyclerview);

    mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3);
    mUserList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mUserList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUserList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            Boolean reachedBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);

            if (reachedBottom){
                loadMoreMessages();
            }
        }
    });

    itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(mItems);

    ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mUserList, false);
    ProfileAdmin activity = (ProfileAdmin) getActivity();
    user_id = activity.getMyData();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Items").child(user_id);

    mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    loadItems();

    return mMainView;
}

private void loadMoreMessages() {
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Items").child(user_id);

    Query itemsRef = mUserDatabase.orderByKey().startAt(oldestkey).limitToLast(10);

    itemsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            ItemsRecyclerView data = dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemsRecyclerView.class);

            oldestkey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            mItems.add(data);

            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(7,0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void loadItems(){
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Items").child(user_id);
    Query query = mUserDatabase.orderByKey().limitToLast(10);

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            ItemsRecyclerView data = dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemsRecyclerView.class);


            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                oldestkey = child.getKey();

                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //now add the list
                mItems.add(data);
                //now add the adapter
                mUserList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

i hope someone understand me and find a solution for that problem.

Comment: What's the problem? I understand that the endless scrolling doesn't work, but what specifically in your code is doing something different than what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use this lib [XRecyclerView](https://github.com/XRecyclerView/XRecyclerView) it supports top loading view and endless recycling

```
xRecyclerView.setLoadingListener(this);
@Override
public void onRefresh() {

}

@Override
public void onLoadMore() {

}
```

for Firebase pagination you can load all data at once and have two arraylists holding the data `List<Data> allData;` and `List<Data> adapterData;`

let's say you will show only 16 items per loading so in your `onLoadMore() method`

```
lastIndex+=16;
adapterData.addAll(d.size()-1, allData.subList(lastIndex, lastIndex+16))
```

lastIndex is a variable in your adapter saving the last loaded index

Comment: can you make more explaining ?

Answer (score 0):

try using this scroll listener with your recyclerview

In load more items place your logic to load more items

isLastPage will return true if there are no items to load

isLoading will be true while you are fetching data and false when you have fetched the data

```
  import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

    /**
     * Pagination class to add more items to the list when reach the last item.
     */
    public abstract class PaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

        /**
         * Supporting only LinearLayoutManager for now.
         *
         * @param layoutManager
         */
        public PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
            this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
                if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount
                        && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
    //                    && totalItemCount >= ClothesFragment.itemsCount
                        ) {
                    loadMoreItems();
                }
            }
        }

        protected abstract void loadMoreItems();

        public abstract boolean isLastPage();

        public abstract boolean isLoading();

    }
```

add this to your recyclerview

```
 public boolean isLastPage;
    public boolean isLoading;
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(your layoutManager) {
            @Override
            protected void loadMoreItems() {
                isLoading=true;
                loadMoreItems();

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLastPage() {
                return isLastPage;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLoading() {
                return isLoading;
            }
        });

   void loadMoreItems() {
        isLoading=false;

        after fetching your data assuming you have fetched list in your recyclerview
        adapter assuming your recyclerview adapter is rvAdapter
        rvAdapter.addData(list);
    }
```

Now in your recyclerview adapter add the following method

Here the list is the list which feeds your recyclerview

```
   void  addData(ArrayList<Object> list) {
            int size = this.list.size();
            this.list.addAll(list);
            int sizeNew = this.list.size();
            notifyItemRangeChanged(size, sizeNew);
        }
```